# List items are missing after submitting the request

Tags: list, sharepoint, listitem

I have one request form and I have submitted the request successfully and popup appears on successful submission of the request which I have received.But when I went to the list items at the backend,I could not find the item that was submitted.
I have checked the recycle bin also and no where it is.

What might be the reason for the request not appearing in the list?Is that because of network issue?Looking weird as I have got the successful notification popup on submitting the request

Comment: You'd better share your sample solution so others could do research.

Comment: Its a very basic nintex form and requsts used to appear in the list after submission but recently 2-3 requests we could not find in the list